# How to parse json object date to Android

Tags: java, android, json, datetime

How to parse json date like  `\/Date(1391802454790-0700)\/`  to  `(01/31/2014 11:44 AM)` in Android.

API Result :

```
{
    "Comment":"ogogog",
    "CommentDate":"\/Date(1391802454790-0700)\/",
    "CommentReply":[
    ],
    "NumberOfLikes":1,   
    "UniqueId":"f786e0da-2e4a-430f-a37c-c60db1901e38",
    "VideoId":65   
}
```

I tried below code but not display like this format (01/31/2014 11:44 AM).

```
String json = "\/Date(1391802454790-0700)\/"; 
//String json = "commentReplyCommentDate";
json=json.replace("/Date(", "").replace("-0700)/", "");
long time = Long.parseLong(json);
Date d= new Date(time);
System.out.println("Dateeee---->"+d);
```

Comment: I would assume the part before the date is the time since epoch in ms, and after the dash is the timezone offset from GMT.  Throw that into a Calendar object and you should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should format `d` Date using `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a`

```
    String json = "/Date(1391802454790-0700)/";
    json=json.replace("/Date(", "").replace("-0700)/", "");
    long time = Long.parseLong(json);
    Date d= new Date(time);
    System.out.println("Dateeee---->"+d);
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a").format(d));
```

Out put:

```
   Dateeee---->Sat Feb 08 01:17:34 IST 2014
   02/08/2014 01:17 AM
```

Comment: thanx, i got the perfect result.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera not working for me .. error say invalid long